# Smallest positive multiplier that when applied to an array renders the array integral

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, boost, eigen

Given an array of `n` non-negative elements, is there a function in any library for C/C++ that returns the ***smallest positive multiplier*** that when applied to each element of the array returns an integer number?

For example, if the array with `n=2` is `1.66667, 2.33333`, the multiplier would be 3. For when we multiply each element of the array with 3, we get `5, 7`, both integer.

If the array is `8,10`, the multiplier would be 0.5. That would give us `4,5`.

(1) Is there an efficient function for this in any of the well-known libraries such as `boost`, `eigen`, etc.?

(2) In case there is nothing available in libraries, what is an efficient algorithm for figuring out the multiple?

Comment: `2.33333 * 3` is `6.99999`, not `7`.

Comment: No, there's no function that does this. You'll need to write your own.

Comment: Seems like a X-Y problem...

Comment: I think at least for floating-point type, it is impossible, because object of floating-point type cannot represent a real number accurately. Maybe you can use a rational number type and implement this function based on such type.

Comment: Floating point numbers can be seen as integer * 2^exponent. You are thus looking for a power of 2 if your multiplier is supposed to be an integer.

Comment: Note that *no* number with a decimal fraction not ending with digit `5` can be exactly represented as an integer divided by a power of two: your input data is inexact but for few exceptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no good solution to your problem in the general case because the values are stored in a floating point format that has finite precision and can only store fractions with denominators powers 2 exactly. For example `0.1 * 10` may very well not be an integral value on your platform.

If you compute the values in the array from integral quantities, you should represent them as normalized fractions with pairs of adequately sized integers and compute the least common multiple of their denominators.

If you want an approximate solution to the problem, you can specify the value of epsilon, and design a solution by hand. I can think of no library function to fit this need, but a brute force solution is easy to write:

```
unsigned long long ullgcd(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b) {
     /* compute the greatest common divisor using Euclid's elegant method */
     if (a < b)
         return ullgcd(b, a);
     else
     if (b == 0)
         return a;
     else
         return ullgcd(b, a % b);
}

double least_multiple(double *a, size_t n, double epsilon) {
    for (double mult = 1;; mult += 1) {
        size_t i;
        unsigned long long div = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            double d = fabs(a[i] * mult);
            unsigned long long v = round(d);
            if (fabs(v - d) > epsilon)
                break;
            div = ullgcd(v, div);
        }
        if (i == n)
            break;
    }
    /* mult is the smallest non zero integer that fits your goal.
       the smallest multiplier is obtained by dividing it 
       by the greatest common divisor of the resulting integer array.
    */
    return mult / div;
}
```

Comment: but in any case, can we not get around it by using an epsilon to conclude proximity to an integer? i.e., if I have an epsilon of 0.0001 in the example above, in the example in my OP, 1.6667 and 2.3333 should get rounded to 4 and 5 respectively due to epsilon?

Comment: If you want an approximate solution to the problem, you can specify the value of epsilon, and design a solution by hand. I can think of no library function to fit this need.

Comment: thanks for the code, but that would not work. Please see that the multiple should be 0.5 for (8,10) That would be missed by your code. I suspect some sort of bisection, etc., may have to be used.

Comment: @Tryer seriously given (8,10) you want 0.5? 8 and 10 are already integers so they actually fit your requirement or? Whatever, you must understand that floating point numbers are poor approximations of real numbers, so exact computation is just impossible.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès The problem is, I want the resultant integer array to be used in a math program where it may be important to have as small coefficients as possible for numerical stability. For e.g, given (3,4.5). 2 is what the code above would return (resultant array (6,9)). Yet, 0.67 multiplier would yield a "smaller array" (2,3)

Comment: @Tryer: I had overlooked the **lowest positive multiplier** constraint. I updated the code, but note that the *lowest positive* multiplier if always `0.0`, you probably want the *lowest strictly positive multiplier*.

Answer (score 4):

Not in the way you've specified no. The problem is the *decimal* values `1.66667` and `2.33333` don't have such a multiplier: you are assuming an approximation which stems from, what is from a mathematical perspective, an arbitrary rounding policy.

And then there are the floating point properties to worry about, so you can rule out anything using a `double` or a `float`.

Your best bet here is to use a fraction class to represent the numbers. Then any common multiplier will drop out with some simple mathematics.

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/rational/index.html

Comment: thanks, unfortunately, some of the array elements are going to be the output from another program that returns general floating point numbers. Do you know if boost can efficiently approximate an arbitrary double value using fractions?

Comment: @Tryer: Such a function would be too "opinion based" or "user dependent", so no. You'd have to build that bit yourself, depending on how much tolerance you'd be prepared to live with. Start with the rational class and have some fun building a construction method that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Rosetta Code's ["Convert decimal number to rational."](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Convert_decimal_number_to_rational#C) Since I am not versed in C, I converted the C code there to Python (even though I think Python may have some relevant libraries) and added a couple of functions that you could easily adapt to C. If the denominators in the fraction conversion are all `1.0`, we divide by the greatest common divisor of the number list. Otherwise, we return the product of the unique denominators.

```py
import math
import operator

def f(arr):
  epsilon = 4
  fractions = [rat_approx(i, 16**epsilon) for i in arr]

  # The denominators in the fraction conversion are all 1.0
  if sum([denom for (num, denom) in fractions]) == len(fractions):
    return 1.0 / gcd_of_many([num for (num, denom) in fractions])
  else:
    # Otherwise, return the product of unique denominators
    return reduce(operator.mul, set([denom for (num, denom) in fractions]), 1)

def gcd(a, b):
  if a < b:
    return gcd(b, a)
  elif b == 0:
    return a;
  else:
    return gcd(b, a % b)

def gcd_of_many(arr):
  result = arr[0]
  for i in xrange(1, len(arr)):
    result = gcd(result, arr[i])
  return result

# Converted from
# https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Convert_decimal_number_to_rational#C
def rat_approx(f, md):
    #  a: continued fraction coefficients.
    h = [0, 1, 0]
    k = [1, 0, 0]
    n = 1
    neg = 0
    num = 0
    denom = 0

    if md <= 1:
      denom = 1
      num = f
      return num, denom

    if f < 0:
      neg = 1
      f = -f

    while f != math.floor(f):
      n <<= 1
      f *= 2

    d = f

    # continued fraction and check denominator each step
    for i in xrange(65):
        a = d // n if n else 0
        if i and not a:
          break

        x = d
        d = n
        n = x % n

        x = a;
        if k[1] * a + k[0] >= md:
            x = (md - k[0]) // k[1]
            if x * 2 >= a or k[1] >= md:
                i = 65
            else:
                break

        h[2] = x * h[1] + h[0]
        h[0] = h[1]
        h[1] = h[2]
        k[2] = x * k[1] + k[0]
        k[0] = k[1]
        k[1] = k[2]

    denom = k[1]
    num = -h[1] if neg else h[1]

    return (num, denom)
```

Output:

```py
   f([8, 10])
=> 0.5
   f([1.66667, 2.33333])
=> 3.0
```

Comment: If n=2, continued fractions (for a[1]/a[0]) are indeed the right approximation tool. For larger n, it becomes messy, as searches for "simultaneous rational approximation", "multidimensional continued fractions", etc show.

Comment: @MarcGlisse thank you for your comment. Could you please provide a (reasonably short) example input that elicits a "messy" procedure/result?

Comment: I meant that mathematically proving some kind of optimality is not hard for n=2 but probably wrong for larger n, since you approximate each number independently (the way you reduce to the same denominator is also strange, but I barely glanced at the code so I won't claim anything).